# Handing ng-repeat and ng-if for dynamic datas from server

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

I have a social media icons where I enable(turns reds color) like button only if my `item.like== 1`or it wont be highlighted (will be in white color)when `item.userid==0`. I am doing this dynamically.so I need to call the function `profileData ()` again when click the like for a particular user. in that case it is like entire page is flickering to load the data which is not looking good.I dont want to call profile data ,instead Need solution so only that particular data alone refresh or turned into like .I tried using ng-show = true and ng-show = false , but that inturn makes all the users icon as true and false.

HTML:

```
<div class="showIcons" ng-repeat="item in pData">

       <a title="Liked">   
       <img  ng-click="unLikeUser(item.userid);" ng-if="(item.like ==1)" class="styleright" src="assets/images/like.png"></a>
       <a title ="Like"> 
      <img  ng-click="likeUser(item.userid);" ng-if="(item.like ==0)" class="styleright otherlike" src="assets/images/like1.png"></a>
               </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.proifleData = function(){
    $scope.pdata = res.response.data;
};
```

likeuser()

for unlikeUser(same function with addorremove:0)

```
    $scope.likeUser= function(like){
          var json = {
              "request": {
                "service": {
                  "servicetype": "9",
                  "functiontype": "9000",
                "session_id": $cookieStore.get('sessionid')

                },
                "data": {
                  "like": [
                    like
                  ],
                  "addorremove": 1
                }
              }
            }
      UserService.getSocialMedia(json).then(function (res) {   


         $scope.profileData();                });
  };
```

JSON:

```
  $scope.pData = [
  [
    {
      "profileInfo": {
        "firstname": "shruthi",
        "lastname": "p",
        "like": 1,

      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "profileInfo": {
        "firstname": "talentnew",
        "lastname": "new",
          "like": 0,

      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "profileInfo": {
        "firstname": "jay",
        "lastname": "sree",
             "like": 0,

      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "profileInfo": {
        "firstname": "ja",
        "lastname": "sr",
        "like": 1,

      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "count": 84
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: I am not able to understand this "or it wont be highlighted when item.userid==0. I am doing this dynamically.so I need to call the function profileData () again when i like the user. "?

Comment: do you think this question is meaningful? what are you trying to convey.. make it meaningful

Answer (score 0):

When user press like get the whole item object into your controller.

**View**

```
ng-click="likeUser(item)"
```

**Controller**

- Get a deep copy of item object (itemCopy)
- Use  itemCopy object to increment like count at first place. this
  will not update the view.
- Use this object instead of item object if you are plan to use item
  object in server request.
- After that send the like count update request to server then have
  the success request
- Then increment the like count inside the item object that is passed
  as a parameter. This will update the particular user like count in
  view because you are using same object reference

```js
$scope.likeUser = function(item) {
  var itemCopy = angular.copy(itme); // get a deep copy
}
```

You  could do same for the dislike event also. Hope this will help to your.